# increasing margins for a single page in KOMA class

Tags: floats, margins, koma-script

I am using the following KOMA document class

```
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
```

everything is fine except that at one point I include 4 pictures in one single page and, due to the margins, they all appear too small.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\footnotesize
 \caption{volume}\label{graph:volume}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,font=footnotesize}
\caption*{nice caption}
\hspace*{\fill}%
  \subfigure[one]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{one.png}}\hfill
   \subfigure[two]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{two.png}}
   \hspace*{\fill} \\
   \hspace*{\fill}%
  \subfigure[three]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{three.png}}\hfill
   \subfigure[four]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{four.png}}
   \hspace*{\fill}%
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

How can I specify some very small margins for **this page** only, without using the package geometry (that seems not compatible with the KOMA class) ?

many thanks!

Comment: you can use `KOMAoptions` inside your document.

Comment: thank you? which kind of options do you have in mind exactly? thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comment you can work with `\KOMAoptions`:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc,pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\storeareas\meinegespeichertenWerte
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
\areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5\paperwidth}{\textheight}

\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\meinegespeichertenWerte
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT:

Here an expanded example using your figure definition:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc,pagesize,demo]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\storeareas\meinegespeichertenWerte
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
\areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5\paperwidth}{\textheight}

\begin{center}
\centering\footnotesize
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\caption{volume}\label{graph:volume}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,font=footnotesize}
\caption*{nice caption}
\hspace*{\fill}%
  \subfigure[one]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{one.png}}
  \hfill%
  \subfigure[two]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{two.png}}%
  \hspace*{\fill} 

  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \subfigure[three]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{three.png}}%
  \hfill
  \subfigure[four]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{four.png}}%
  \hspace*{\fill}%

\end{center}
\clearpage
\meinegespeichertenWerte
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: marco, I tried your solution but it does not work. the page wont show in landscape mode and the images are overly big...
I typed 

\clearpage
\storeareas\meinegespeichertenWerte
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
\areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5\paperwidth}{\textheight}

+ the code above for the images...

Comment: maybe i am missing something? what means your code \areaset{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5\paperwidth}{\textheight}? thanks again marco

Comment: @Noobie: How do you compile? With pdflatex it works well.

Comment: thanks @marcodaniel for your help. yes your example works (i use pdflatex indeed).. but when i try to adapt it to my code above (the insert figure environment stuff) then it does not... i just need the margin to be a bit wider

Comment: @Noobie: Please see my edit