# How to change the paper margins for a single page in KOMA Script?

Tags: margins, titles, koma-script, typearea

Well, after [set the document in a half legal paper page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325197/seting-koma-script-document-in-half-legal-paper?noredirect=1#comment794701_325197), now I need to create the front page for the document (a PhD thesis) according to the [University guidelines](http://bc.unam.mx/tesisdigital.html).

In a nutshell the challenge is to design the front page with the coat of the university and all the data requested on the cover. Unfortunately the margins I've used in the document (`div=calc`) do not help me, especially the lower one that is very large.

I don't need to reduce the margins throughout the document, hence I don't use the `geometry` package, but I need to do it only with the front page and I think that the `typearea` package is able to do it, simply I don't know how.

I found [this question related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27562/change-page-margins-for-one-single-page-inside-the-document) but I don't need to rotate pages, and then [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142223/increasing-margins-for-a-single-page-in-koma-class) similar but I didn't understand the answer.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,paper=7in:8.5in,DIV=calc,BCOR=5mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\subject{Thesis}
\begin{titlepage}
\scshape
\centering

%\missingfigure{Coat of arms from the UNAM}

{\Large Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México} \\
Programa de Posgrado en Ciencias Políticas y Sociales \\
orientación disciplinaria en sociología \\

\bigskip

{\Large Frontera Vertical:\\ {\large Perspectiva Analítica para estudiar los procesos sociales en el  tránsito de centroamericanos a Estados Unidos}}

\bigskip

{\LARGE tesis}  \\
que para optar por el grado de  \\
doctora en Ciencias Políticas y Sociales \\

\medskip

presenta:\\
{\large Me}

\bigskip

Tutores: \\
{\small \raggedright
Dr. Lorenzo Alejandro Méndez Rodríguez (Director de Tesis) | {\footnotesize Instituto de Investigaciones Económicas}\\
Dra. Judith Bokser Liwerant | {\footnotesize Posgrado de Ciencias Políticas y Sociales}\\
Dra. Maritza Caicedo Riascos | {\footnotesize Instituto de Investigaciones Sociales}}

\smallskip

Lectores: \\
{\small \raggedright
Dra. Liliana Rivera Sánchez | {\footnotesize Colegio de México}\\
Dr. Adolfo Sánchez Almanza | {\footnotesize Instituto de Investigaciones Económicas}} 

\medskip

{\raggedright \indent Ciudad Universitaria, Ciudad de México, \today}
\end{titlepage}

% the rest of the document...

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234794/82917) may help.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you would like to change the margins on the titlepage only? If so, you could do it the hackish way: Use the addmargin environment to make it broad or thin, `\vspace*{-1cm}` to draw a smaller top margin eg., and `\enlargethispage{3cm}`to enlarge the page.

Comment: @campa I don't know how I didn't see before, dhame on me, I should search better -_\

Thanks Keks Dose looks interesting that trick.

Comment: You could also create the entire title page using \tikz[remember picture, overlay] and ignore the margins.

Comment: @JohnKormyloit's a good idea, but my knowledge about tikz are limited, rather incipient. Do you have any example or know of any that can serve for this?