# How to stretch the text area of a single page using Koma classes?

Tags: titles, typearea

A very similar questions has been asked here: [increasing margins for a single page in koma class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142223/increasing-margins-for-a-single-page-in-koma-class) and he solved his problem changing the page orientation from portrait to landscape. In my case I cannot do that as I am typesseting a title page.

I am using the Koma class scrreprt with the classicthesis package to define the overall format of my document. (actually using the infamous classicthesis template).

My question is: How could the margins for the titlepage only could be stretched to the paper larger borders? I mean I don't have a problem with the top and bottom margin.

I found another similar question here: [Changing the top margin of one single page with typearea package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/changing-the-top-margin-of-one-single-page-with-typearea-package) in wich they achieved what I want to do apart from the fact that they enlarged the top margin instead of the text area. I believe that I could do something similar to solve my situation but I don't have any idea on how to do that.

Thank's in advance to everybody

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{typearea}
\areaset[current]{312pt}{761pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\pdfbookmark[1]{Titel}{title}
%*******************************************************
\begin{titlepage}
    % if you want the titlepage to be centered, uncomment and fine-tune the line below (KOMA classes environment)

    \begin{addmargin}[-0.5cm]{-3cm}
        \scalebox{1.3}{

            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][c]{0.2\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{Logo_ITC_cl.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}

            \begin{minipage}[c][0.1\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    {\scshape University of Somewhere}
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    \hrule height2.5pt
                    \vspace{.1cm}
                    \hrule height1pt
                    \vspace{.3cm}
                    {\scshape  My major's Department}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }

        \scalebox{1.3}{
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.2\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \hskip2pt
                    \vrule width2.5pt height14cm
                    \hskip1mm
                    \vrule width1pt height14cm \\
                    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{Logo-TecNM.pdf}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[c][0.6\textheight][t]{0.65\textwidth}
                \vspace*{1cm}
                \begin{center}
                    {\begingroup\color{Maroon}\scshape{\spacedallcaps{This is an extremely long title wich will span in multiple lines and with this margin setup won't look as good as it could}} 
                        \endgroup}

                    \vspace{1cm}

                    \makebox[5cm][c]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Memoria de Residencia Profesional}}  \\[1cm]
                    {\spacedlowsmallcaps {que para obtener el título de:}}\\[5pt]
                    {\scshape{Overly Complicated Major}}\\[1cm]            
                    {\spacedlowsmallcaps {presenta:}}\\[5pt]
                    {\scshape{Jhon Doe}}


                    \vfill

                    {\spacedlowsmallcaps {Somewhere, Sometime}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have addmargin in your code. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Johannes_B I thought about that but I ended using it to center the title page, if I decrease the indentation everything moves to the left but looks very much the same

Comment: Addmargin is used to add a margin (also negative sizes), not to center anything.

Comment: Johannes_B Of course, the thing is that if I switch the left indentation to -3 cm my title page appears closer to the left border of the page but the text lines remain spanning over the same lines, I want to have a wider text area, I don't know if I am being clear enough.

Comment: You can adjust all by removing the brackets (i think) or use a proper value in the brackets. Have a look at the manual.

Comment: Use the `changepage` package which lets you change the margins (plus or minus) for a block of text or for a complete page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\storeareas` to save your layout settings and restore it later.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=right,BCOR=5mm,
  areasetadvanced% <-  added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}% it is not recommended with a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout

\AfterSettingArea{%
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{7em}%
  \setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}%
}
\areaset[current]{312pt}{761pt}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
First page with main settings
\clearpage
Second page with main settings

\storeareas\mystoredareavalues
\areaset[0pt]{425pt}{761pt}
Page with changed areas
\mystoredareavalues

Page with restored areas
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `scrreprt` loads package `typearea` automatically. Package `classicthesis` loads and uses eg. package `titlesec` which is incompatible with KOMA-Script.